# What's the best way to get an APK for app update?

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

I'm creating an App Updater for my android App and since the app can't go on the Play Store I need to get my APK from somewhere else. I'm already getting a JSON through an HTTP Request from my server that contains the version of the latest app. Is there a way to send the APK within that JSON to be downloaded after? If so I would appreciate some insight into how that is done. If there is a bette way I'm all ears too!

Comment: The question seems confused, if you download a JSON file, should it not contain the URI/path on your server of where the new APK is? Depending on how you need to update the APK, you can then start downloading OR prompt the user so that the download doesn't get interrupted.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Sorry for the confusion, currently the JSON only contains the latest version code of the APK (as in version 2 or version 2.5) for comparison with the APK installed on the device, my question was if I can send the APK, held on the server, within that same JSON so that if an update is required I can download it to the device and replace the old one. And if it is possible, how do I do it?

Comment: Passing in a large binary blob that could be dozens or hundreds of MB would be a bad idea.  It would be possible, but you're better off putting the URL of the file and downloading it separately.

Comment: @GabeSechan So, make an HTTP Request to the server for the APK? And then use something like DownloadManager to download it.